# UPS sharepoint 2016 adfs add connection

Tags: adfs, ups

we have a sharepoint 2016 on prem with an user profile connection configured for active directory.
we have also an claim provider for ADFS for the same domain used in an extranet scenario.
When we try to add the the 'synchronization connection' configured with the ADFS claim provider we get

Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ADImportDCMapping' with unique index 'IX_ADImportDcMapping_DCName'. The duplicate key value is (edited.local, DC=edited,DC=local). 
The statement has been terminated.

is it possible to add a second connection to the same domain with a different authentication provider?
we have a similar setup on an sharepoint 2013 that gave us no issue and on the profile config database we see no rows, while in the sharepoint 2016 profile  we effectively see one row.

we have also tried different contaner but the definition of the index IX_ADImportDcMapping_DCName prevent us from using the same domain.

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not do this.

You will produce (or can't :)) duplicate User Profiles. This breaks various OAuth scenarios. In addition, a user cannot have two identity providers and be considered the same identity. That is, if a user logs in with Windows Claims auth, their SAML identity will not be considered the *same* user when it comes to SharePoint permissions.

Comment: thanks for the info, but I'm missing something: i have 2 distinct profiles, one for the ADFS and the other for Windows. How can I retrieve the property for the user when i'm logged from ADFS in the extranet scenario? thanks again

Comment: I think that the right way to go is to setup MIM based on the following post: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/adamsorenson/2018/01/31/sharepoint-2016-mim-and-samlfba-user-profiles/

Comment: Again, do not do this. You do not want duplicate profiles. It will cause OAuth connections that rely on Profiles like to Workflow Manager to fail. Your user's permissions will also not be the same -- you would need to add a user to a permission with both Windows claims and SAML. Pick a single authentication method for _all_ users and stick with it. Or use an AD FS non-claims relying party so you can continue to use Windows Claims.

Comment: do you suggest an approach similar to: https://www.helloitsliam.com/2015/10/18/sharepoint-and-adfs-claims/?

Comment: I suggest not using SAML at all. Look into https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/create-a-non-claims-aware-relying-party-trust.

Answer (score -1):

thanks Trevor, you shed some light in a very obscure matter for me. I think that I've always integrate ADFS with sharepoint in the wrong way. time to review my whole idea on plan extranet access to sharepoint by ADFS.